# How to return multiple tables with one method?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have a class, which methods are to be used as web services (REST) -> XML output. It is for getting some data from db, which could be used to import from excel.

While I had to return just one table, there was no problem (method looks like this):

```
public DataTable CountryKitUPH(string date, string fhour, string thour)
{
     date = Dates(date);

     var from = date + ' ' + fhour + ":00";
     var to = date + ' ' + thour + ":00";

     var sqlCommand = "exec rptPMCountryKitUPH_sp @trantype='REPORT', @fromdt='" + from + "', @todt='" + to + "'";

     var dataContext = DataContextFactory.GetShopFloorDataContext(Guid.Empty);
     var dt = Core.Data.Utility.QueryToDataTable(Guid.Empty, DataContextFactory.SecurityKey, sqlCommand);
     dt.TableName = "Country Kit UPH";
     return dt;
}
```

But now I have to do report, which returns multiple tables - one set of tables for each "line" parameter.

And the method should return more of those. I can imagine how it could look as XML, I just have no idea how to return it (and as I cannot post images yet, I will try to write how I think the XML should look like:

```
<line name='L1'>
    <minitable>
        <row no="1">
            <column name="event 1">13</column>
            <column name="event 2">35</column>
            <column name="event 3">78</column>
        </row>
    </minitable>
    <table>
        (content)
    </table>
</line>
<line name='L2'>
    <minitable>
        (content)
    </minitable>
    <table>
        (content)
    </table>
</line>
```

So please - what data type should I pick to return multiple tables like this, or, how to wrap those in xml?

Thanks a lot

Comment: List<DataTable> seems like it would be appropriate if you need them as datatables and you already have your code setup to get datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like this?

```
public DataTable[] MultipleMethod(args)
{
    List<DataTable> list = new List<DataTable>();

    // Load first DataTable
    DataTable dt = ...
    list.Add(dt);  // Add the DataTable to the list of tables

    // Load second DataTable
    dt = ...
    list.Add(dt);  // Add the DataTable to the list of tables

    // Load another DataTable
    dt = ...
    list.Add(dt);  // Add the DataTable to the list of tables

    return list.ToArray();  // Return an array of tables (can return the list if that is the return type)
}
```